# Evaluation of a limit of piece-wisely defined functions

Tags: limits

> Suppose that we're given two piece-wisely defined functions, where $g$
> is everywhere continuous:
>
> $$f(x) = \begin{cases}ax-1,\space\space x<4\\\ bx+3, \space\space
>  x\geq 4\end{cases}$$
>
> $$g(x) = \begin{cases}(a+b)x+4,\space\space x<1\\\ 2b+1,\space\space
>  x\geq 1\end{cases}$$
>
> What is $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^{+}}f(5-x)-2\lim_{x\rightarrow 3^{-}}g(x-2)$?

Since $g$ is continuous everywhere, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^{+}}g(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 1^{-}}g(x)$ and so $(a+b)+4 = 2b+1$, leading us to $b = a+3$.

To use the definition we're given, I thought of performing a change of variable as follows:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^{+}}f(5-x) = \lim_{y\rightarrow 4^{+}}f(y)$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 3^{-}}g(x-2) = \lim_{z\rightarrow 1^{-}}g(z)$$

However, I am not sure about this change of variables $y = x-5$, $z = x-2$ for one-sided limits. Could I hear your feedback?

**EDIT:** $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^{+}}f(5-x) = L$ if and only if for every for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for every $x$, $$0<x-1<\delta\implies 0<|f(5-x)-L|<\epsilon$$

Where

$$0<x-1<\delta\space\equiv\space 0<4-(5-x)<\delta$$

Therefore for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for every $y = 5-x$,

$$0<4-y<\delta \implies |f(y)-L|<\epsilon$$

Which is equivalent to $\lim_{y\rightarrow 4^{-}}f(y) = L$. Thus, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^{+}}f(x) = \lim_{y\rightarrow 4^{-}}f(y)$.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to1^+}f(5-x)=\lim_{y\to4^-}f(y)$ since if $x=1+\varepsilon\Longrightarrow y=5-(1+\varepsilon)=4-\varepsilon$ for $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: @VincentBatens, please don't answer questions in the comments

Comment: @SammyBlack ye fair, a one-liner didn't seem worth it to write an answer, but it's not the way things should go of course. I'm happy to let the rep to you for the right answer.

Comment: Happily, our answers are almost identical. :-)

Comment: I tried to prove in the recent edit, by using $\delta$-$\epsilon$ approach, the statement you've given in comments.

Comment: Can you provide a feedback for $\delta$-$\epsilon$ approach, if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one-sided limit, where $x \to 1^+$ involves values $x = 1 + \varepsilon$ for ever smaller $\varepsilon > 0$. Under the change-of-variables $y = 5 - x$, we have  $y = 5 - x = 4 - \varepsilon$, so $y \to 4^-$, i.e.
$$
\lim_{x \to 1^+} f(5-x) = \lim_{y \to 4^-} f(y). 
$$